# How to Reorder Shopify Payment Methods?

Tags: shopify

I want to rearrange payment options on checkout page. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OlO7.png)

Actually I did not found any solutions or methods for that particular issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.

I found a solution after trying a lot of different things.

Third party app allows basic Shopify stores to reorder/hide/rename payment methods conditionally.

In my case I'm using Payfy Shopify App.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using a Shopify Plus plan, you can't do this. [Read more here](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/checkout-extensibility).

Comment: Thanks for answer, yet small business.